# Parametric equations of an ellipse in an arbitrary plane at an arbitrary orientation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

I have searched both on here and on stackoverflow for answers to this question and I can't seem to find a good answer relating to what I'm doing.

I have a center point and two vectors, one that is in the minor axis direction with minor radius length and one that is in the major axis direction with major radius length. From this, I need to be able to generate points along the path of an ellipse of arbitrary orientation in an arbitrary plane. Can I define an ellipse using just these three things? And how?

Comment: What is the ambient space? $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Should be extendable to $\mathbb{R}^n$ later, but I'm fine with just $\mathbb{R}^3$ right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you an ellipse around point P with axis vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$
$$\mathbf{r} = P + \mathbf{u} \cos(t) + \mathbf{v} \sin(t)$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "axis vectors" in this context. The ellipse isn't axis-aligned. Are you meaning $\mathbf{u}$ and  $\mathbf{v}$ are in the direction of the major and minor vectors, respectfully?

Comment: I ask because I've been using this exact equation in my code. I think I may be misinterpreting some part of this equation, as my code is not working as expected.

Comment: @TheRobotCarlson Not only should $\mathbb u$ and $\mathbb v$ lie in the directions of the major and minor axes, their lengths should be equal to the semimajor and semiminor axis lengths.

Comment: It turns out that my math wasn't the problem after all, I made a very simple mistake in my code that wasn't showing up in the unit tests. Thank you for helping me reach that conclusion! I've accepted your answer as it is correct.